# How to install "pymssql" module in python 2.7?

Tags: python, pymssql

I have already installed pymssql module and it was installed successfully. 
But when I try to run my script it still ask to install pymssql module. 
Not sure if I am missing anything here.

Reference[PyMSSQL](http://www.pymssql.org/en/latest/)

Comment: How did you istall it? What is the error messege?

Comment: i installed it using pip coomand #pip install pymssql

Comment: what is the error messege?

Comment: I used following code to check for pymssql and I always get output "please install pymssql module first".                                                                                     try:
    import pymssql
except ImportError:
    print("Pls install the pymssql module first")
    exit(1)

Comment: remove the exception. . what is the real error message?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I remove exception then there is no error displayed and automation won't run. I added exception message to check if module is installed correctly.

Comment: in your exception., use this: except Exception as e: print(e)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing FREETDS before running "pip install pymssql"

Run this to install FREETDS > sudo apt-get install freetds-dev

Answer (score 0):

You need to have FreeTDS installed on your computer. However, you can run into an error using the latest FreeTDS version.

If you are using Mac OS, you can run the following:

brew unlink freetds; 
brew install freetds@0.91;
brew link --force freetds@0.91;

Then install pymssql: sudo pip install pymssql

This will force a symlink to the older version of freeTDS, and in my opinion, more stable.

Some more information can be found here: https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/432

Cheers.